# How to install service on macOS with custom arguments in install4j?

Tags: install4j

The *`Install a service`* action supports calling the service executable with custom arguments on `windows`. I don't see any option to do that on `macOS`. Is that possible?

One workaround seems to be to create a separate service launcher for `macOS` that passes in the arguments, but I'd like to avoid creating separate launchers for each `OS` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The "Install a service" action implements several OS-specific features for services that depend on the capabilities of the OS. The "Windows arguments" property is a such a case. macOS does not have an "arguments at install time" feature for daemons, so the action does not support it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The LaunchDaemon plist files can include arguments that are passed in to the program. Is it possible to incorporate similar functionality to the plist files generated by install4j? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/getting-launchd-to-read-program-arguments-correctly

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've added it to our issue tracker.